# Tabs over-shadows the content in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a form in html. If I add tabs at the bottom to take me to different pages, it doesn't allow me to submit the form. Nothing happens. Appears as if its not receiving the click. If I remove the tabs, it works fine. Also, vertical scroll doesn't seem to work. Am I not using tabs rightly?

Following is my html -

```
<ion-header id="main-content">
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Add Assignment</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-card id="card-add-assignment">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>Add Assignment</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <form [formGroup]="addAssignmentForm" (ngSubmit)="addAssignment()">
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label position="floating">Assignment Title</ion-label>
                    <ion-input formControlName="title"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label position="floating">Description</ion-label>
                    <ion-textarea rows="10" formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-button
                    id="add-assignment-button"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    [disabled]="!addAssignmentForm.valid"
                    >ADD ASSIGNMENT</ion-button
                >
            </form>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button routerLink="/home/add-student">
                <ion-icon name="albums"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Add Student</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
            <ion-tab-button routerLink="/home/view-student">
                <ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>View Student</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

Unable to click button as in attached screenshot -

[image]

If I try to see the button in `dev-console`, it highlights the whole `router-outlet`
[image]

My `app-routing.module.ts` -

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomePage } from './home/home.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    /* { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }, */
    /* { path: 'sidemenu', loadChildren: './sidemenu/sidemenu.module#SidemenuPageModule' },
    { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' }, */
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomePage,
        children: [
            { path: '', loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule' },
            { path: 'schedule', loadChildren: './conference/schedule/schedule.module#SchedulePageModule' },
            { path: 'attend', loadChildren: './conference/attend/attend.module#AttendPageModule' },
            { path: 'add-batch', loadChildren: './batch/add-batch/add-batch.module#AddBatchPageModule' },
            { path: 'view-batch', loadChildren: './batch/view-batch/view-batch.module#ViewBatchPageModule' },

            {
                path: 'add-assignment',
                loadChildren: './assignment/add-assignment/add-assignment.module#AddAssignmentPageModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'view-assignment',
                loadChildren: './assignment/view-assignment/view-assignment.module#ViewAssignmentPageModule',
            },
            { path: 'add-student', loadChildren: './student/add-student/add-student.module#AddStudentPageModule' },
            { path: 'view-student', loadChildren: './student/view-student/view-student.module#ViewStudentPageModule' },
        ],
    },
    { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```